# Calculating similarity -> python code to php code - Whats wrong?

Tags: php, python, similarity

I am trying to convert the following python code to a PHP code. Can you please explain me what is wrong in my PHP code, because I do not get the same results. If you need example data please let me know.

```
# Returns a distance-based similarity score for person1 and person2

def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
    # Get the list of shared_items 
    si={} 
    for item in prefs[person1]:
        if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1
    # if they have no ratings in common, return 0 
    if len(si)==0: return 0

    # Add up the squares of all the differences 

    sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
        for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]]) 

    return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

My PHP code:

```
$sum  = 0.0;

foreach($arr[$person1] as $item => $val)
{
    if(array_key_exists($item, $arr[$person2]))
    {
        $p = sqrt(pow($arr[$person1][$item] - $arr[$person2][$item], 2));
        $sum = $sum + $p;
    }
}


$sum = 1 / (1 + $sum);

echo $sum;
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: please fix the indenting for your python script. whitespace is imporant

Comment: also, there's no square-rooting in the python script. your code is doing something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is close as i could make a direct translation... (untested)

```
function sim_distance($prefs, $person1, $person2) {
    $si = array();
    foreach($prefs[$person1] as $item) {
        if($item in $prefs[$person2]) $si[$item]=1;
    }
    if(count($si)==0) return 0;

    $squares = array();
    foreach($prefs[$person1] as $item) {
        if(array_key_exists($item,$prefs[$person2])) {
            $squares[] = pow($prefs[$person1][$item]-$prefs[$person2][$item],2);
        }
    }
    $sum_of_squares = array_sum($squares);
    return 1/(1+$sum_of_squares);
}
```

I don't really know what you're trying to do, or if I've interpreted the indentation correctly...but maybe this'll help. I'm assuming your data structures have the same layout as in the python script.

oh...and i'm interpreting the python as this:

```
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
    # Get the list of shared_items 
    si={} 
    for item in prefs[person1]:
        if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1

    # if they have no ratings in common, return 0 
    if len(si)==0: return 0

    # Add up the squares of all the differences
    sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]]) 

    return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much it helps posting an untested translation, bc now the OP has *two* suspect PHP versions to debug. I tested it and found some regressions in your version over the original.

Comment: eh...oh well. if he posted the test data and expected result it would be easier to test.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. The code is just for looking similarities in a database to generate some recommendations for other users...

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that you've added `sqrt` to the PHP code. The PHP also doesn't handle the special case of no prefs in common, which gives 0 in the python version and 1 in the PHP version.

I tested both versions and those are the only differences I found.

Comment: Also note: the python code has some issues. The line `return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)` should probably be `return 1.0/(1+sum_of_squares)` so it will do float division even if all inputs are integers. The entire top section of the function could also be rewritten `if not any(item in prefs[person2] for item in prefs[person1]): return 0`.